# how to access list of fieldapinames in apex

Tags: apex

```
List<contact> conlst = new List<contact>();

conlst = (contact:{BusinessPortal__c=true, Id=a695ExxxxxjxQAG, RecordTypeId=0126MxxxxxIUxxY, CurrencyIsoCode=EUR},{customportal__c=true, Id=a695ExxxxxjxQAG, RecordTypeId=0126MxxxxxIUxxY, CurrencyIsoCode=EUR})
```

I need this list in map as below Key value pair of contact list as {apiname,fieldvalue}

expected result : {{BusinessPortal__c,true},{customportal__c,true}}

Comment: Start from the [Schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) API.

Comment: without using the schema api is there any other alterative existing method names ?

Comment: There are [SObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) methods that can help with the specific data in a given in-memory record, but you only get those fields that were explicitly queried.

Comment: I am talking about [getPopulatedFieldsAsMap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap). You can get the key set which lists the field API names. You can query the fields' values using those returned names via the `get` method on SObject.

Comment: BYW, why not use the Schema API? Is this some interview question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base API for all in-memory records is called [SObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

This base class includes methods for finding the data that is currently loaded and available in-memory for that record. This corresponds to the fields that were queried or that have been explicitly set and is called `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap`.

This method returns a `Map<String, Object>` where the keys are the fully qualified field names and the values are the actual field values returned as the ultimate base class for all types of value in Apex, `Object`.

You can get the `Set` of populated fields' names using that map's `keySet`.

Comment: thanks @phil this worked for me

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to mark as best answer to ensure the question is marked as solved.